# npx react-native init MyTestApp command is not installing the react-native in MAC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

## ISSUE

I'm trying to install and run the react native todo command - npx react-native init MyTestApp in my local MacBook Pro. The following are the issues I'm facing:

here is the actual github issue: [enter link  here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28661)

May I know what are the steps I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

With Latest react-native version, make sure everything is latest too.

Here's the latest compatibility

```
MacOS Catalina : 10.15.4
Xcode version  : 11.4 (11E146)
Pod version.   : 1.9.1
```

Note: My answer is limited to mac only. I was also facing this issue, this is how i am able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying installing the Xcode developer tools

> xcode-select --install

or try force resetting it if it's already installed.

> sudo xcode-select --reset